# How can I construct a Band-pass filter from a low and a high-pass filter?

Tags: image-processing, lowpass-filter, opencv, bandpass, highpass-filter

Suppose, I need to construct a Band-pass filter in OpenCV. But, I know, there are no functions in OpenCV for Band-pass filters.

Now, what I need to do is to have a low-pass filter and a high-pass filter and combine them as a **series**. That is, first, the image would be passed through a low-pass filter and then the output of that low-pass filter would be passed to a high-pass filter.

**Am I correct?**

Now, what kind of low and high pass filters should I use? Would they be,

- Gassian low/high pass filters
- Mean low/high pass filters
- Median low/high pass filters
- Sobel filters
- or, anything else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct. You apply them if series in they are linear.

One simple band-pass filter you could use is called the [difference of Gaussian (DoG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians)

The procedure is:

1. Create a Gaussian filter with a small variance
2. Create a Gaussian filter with a large variance
3. Subtract the latter from the former to create a band-pass filter
4. Apply the filter to the image

There are a lot of different filters to choose from depending on the application. A good paper is ["On the choice of band-pass quadrature filters"](https://www.hds.utc.fr/~dboukerr/Papers/Qf_JMIV_2004.pdf) by Boukerroui, Noble and Brady. It has an analysis of the DoG filter as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832557/band-stop-filter-mask-based-on-low-high-pass-filter-mask-opencv/26833232#26833232

Do "Band-pass" and "Band-stop" mean same things?

Comment: No, band stop is the reverse of the band pass. That is, it attenuates a range of frequencies rather than amplifying them. High pass followed by low pass (with Fhigh<Flow) would result in bandpass. Highpass in parallel with Lowpass (with FHigh>Flow) would result in band stop.